# Regular Expression in java for replacing second occurence in a matched pattern

Tags: java, regex

Actually i have string in java having the some html content now i want to replace with some other html content by using regular expressions in java

```
String htmlData="<textarea style="display:none"/> some other data here <textarea/> some more other data here <input type="text"/>";
```

Now i want to replace like the following :

```
    String htmlData="<textarea style="display:none"></textarea> some other data here <textarea></textarea> some more other data here <input type="text"/>";
```

means that i need to change all self close textarea tags to right syntax textarea tags.

Here is what I tried:

```
 String htmlData = htmlData.replace("<textarea/>","<textarea></textarea>");
```

But how can I find textarea nodes that have attributes ?

Comment: Your question doesn't explain what you've done to try and solve the problem; it currently reads like a request for code. Please share your attempted implementation and explain how it fails to meet your requirements.

Comment: I got enlightened a few days back. Your turn! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work or you:

```
htmlData = htmlData.replaceAll("(<textarea[^>]*)/>", "$1></textarea>");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this has anything to do with a "second occurrence", but this should work:

```
htmlData = htmlData.replaceAll("(<textarea[^/]*)/>", "$1></textarea>");
```

---

Some test code:

```
String htmlData = "<textarea style=\"display:none\"/> some other data here <textarea/> some more other data here <input type=\"text\"/>";
htmlData = htmlData.replaceAll("(<textarea[^/]*)/>", "$1></textarea>");
System.out.println(htmlData);
```

Output:

```
<textarea style="display:none"></textarea> some other data here <textarea></textarea> some more other data here <input type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<textarea[^/]*/>
```